# Replace name of .csproject file in VSIX

Tags: c#, vsix, visual-studio-templates

I created a VSIX which is creating a Project file with some additional Files.
The replacement auf my files is working Properly but my project file is not renamed properly.

Short example. I create a Project of Foo. Assemblyname should be MY.Foo and Projectfile should also be My.Foo even if I named the Projektname just Foo.

### VS:Template

```
 <VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>ClusterTemplate</Name>
    <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>ClusterTemplate</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="My.$projectname$.csproj" File="Test.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="I$projectname$Cluster.cs">ITestCluster.cs</ProjectItem>
      <Folder Name="PrintTemplates" TargetFolderName="PrintTemplates" />
      <Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
      <Folder Name="TemplateFactories" TargetFolderName="TemplateFactories" />
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$projectname$Cluster.cs">TestCluster.cs</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$projectname$RopeTarget.cs">TestRopeTarget.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

### Snippet of .csproj template file

```
<RootNamespace>MY.$safeprojectname$</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>MY.$safeprojectname$</AssemblyName>
```

So the end result is that Assemblyname and Namespace aswell as all files a renamed correctly beside my .csproj file. He remains with my input Foo.

How can I rename the .csproj file with VSIX/VSTemplate

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm way late to this.  But when I added a similar thing to mine, I just didn't include the TargetFileName and the project gets named whatever I type into the dialogs that come up after I selected my project template.

```
<Project File="ProjectTemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">...</Project>
```